# jQuery Full Calendar - scroll while dragging past bottom of screen

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

We have a utility built using the jQuery Full calendar.

Currently, if a user tries to create a new event and drag the time past the bottom of the screen (e.g. screen cuts off at 3:00pm, and they want to drag down to 5:00pm), the screen won't scroll.

Is there another utility that can be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no actual way to do this without hacking the js.

One thing that you could do is an onmousemove event that fires on your calendar element and then onDragStart event set a variable called "dragging" (or something like that) to true and within the mousemove event... in psuedo... if dragging === true than get mouse coordinates and then scrollTop to location. onDragStop change var dragging to false. Make sure to unbind the event though so it doesn't interfere with the rest of the calendar.

Just an idea off the top of my head... not tested.